# Get data from Redux thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've just started implementing Redux in a React application, and it's the first time i try to, so please bear with me.
My problem is that i can't access the data in my component this `this.props.questions`

I have a simple action which is supposed to async fetch some data

```
export function fetchQuestions(url) {
    const request = axios.get('url');

    return (dispatch) => {
        request.then(({data}) => {
            dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_QUESTIONS', payload: data });
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
}
```

Which is picked up my reducer `questions_reducer`

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
   switch(action.type) {
       case 'FETCH_QUESTIONS':
           console.log('Getting here');
           return state.concat([action.payload.data]);
           console.log('But not here');
   }
   return state;
}
```

My `index` reducer looks like this:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import fetchQuestions from './question_reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    questions: fetchQuestions
});

export default rootReducer;
```

I pass it to my store where i apply the `thunk` middleware and finally into `<Provider store={store}>` which wraps my app, but the prop just returns `undefined` in my React component

configureStore:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );
}
```

I don't know if the console.log is to be trusted but it logs from my questions_reducer before the data is returned from the dispatch in my action

EDIT (Component)

```
class QuestionsRoute extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       this.props.fetch('someUrl);
       setTimeout(function(){ console.log(this.props.questions) }, 
       1500);
    }

    render() {
       {console.log(this.props.questions)}
       return (
          <div>
             <1>Hello</1>
                {this.props.questions !== undefined ?
                   <p>We like props</p>: <p>or not</p>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        questions: state.questions,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetch: () => dispatch(fetchQuestions())
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(QuestionsRoute);
```

Comment: How are you trying to access the `prop` in your component - is it properly connected with `connect()`?

Comment: Can you share your component code?

Comment: Yes it is. I have a mapStateToProps which returns questions: state.questions, and i access it with this.props.questions

Comment: Its there now - I believe the problem is that `action.payload.data` in my questions_reducer returns undefined

Comment: @Fripo print the payload value here `console.log('Getting here', action.payload);` and check the result, let us know about it.

Comment: It returns the object im expecting. Can i just concat the object with the state = [] as im doing now, or is this my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your reducer

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
   switch(action.type) {
       case 'FETCH_QUESTIONS':
           return state.concat([action.payload.data]);
   }
   return state;
}
```

You should probably instead have `return state.concat([action.payload]);`

Since from `dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_QUESTIONS', payload: data });` we see that `payload` *is* `data`, it doesn't contain it.

Update: I'd recommend setting up `redux-devtools` / `redux-devtools-extension` / `react-native-debugger` so you can visually see your actions and store state live - makes things like this a lot easier to debug!

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just figured that out, when asked to log payload and not payload.data. Thanks though!

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't spot it in time to save you time! I've added a recommendation to my answer that might help you spot these things in future though. Feel free to accept ;)